# How to extend dropdown menu to fit list items inside

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, nav

The list items (processing and iOS) inside the "Projects" dropdown menu are cut off when you hover in a smaller screen size. They also overlap with the other menu items. Check it out at https://willhay.io/masonry. How can I make it so they aren't cut off and don't overlap with the other menu items? Also how can I remove the grey background-color of the menu button on hover? Thanks for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user3881935 yes but centered

Comment: Center like they are now

Comment: @user3881935 I like it better on hover not click

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81817/discussion-between-user3881935-and-darkstar).

Answer (score 0):

append this codes to your @media (max-width:798px)

```
.noStyle {
    background-color: #888;
    width: 40%;
    right: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
.noStyle > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.noStyle > li > ul {
    position: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #444;
}
```

Comment: That kind of fixes it but I want the layout of the nav to remain the same like this http://imgur.com/lvjWmdO with no grey boxes.

Comment: @Darkstar : Please speak beginner to me, My English is terrible I cant understand. you need grey background ?